# Initialize Firebase in private NPM package with App.initializeApp() from parent

Tags: javascript, npm, google-cloud-firestore

we created a private npm package to share some React views between two projects. Both are using Firestore and I want even the View from the NPM package use the config of the parent.

When including the view of my private NPM package in my project, I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).
```

Here is a mocked version:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
initializeApp(window.config);

// comes from a private NPM package
import {ExternalView} from "@some-orga/custom-views";

import {
  MainWrapper
} from "./styles";


const db = getFirestore(app);
const AdPreviewWrapper = ({
  user
}) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    //some firebase call
    db.collection("locations").get()...

  }, [user]);

  return (
    <MainWrapper>
      
        <ExternalView
          user={user}
          clientView={true}
        />
      
    </MainWrapper>
  );
};

export default AdPreviewWrapper;
```

`ExternalView` is the view that is calling Firestore internally.

Is it possible that the view from the npm package is relying in the local `Firebase App.initializeApp()`?

Versions on the frontend:

```
// package.json
"firebase": "9.22.1",
"react": "^16.14.0"
```